# How to install electron in ubuntu 14.04 os?

Tags: linux, electron

I am having trouble installing electron in Ubuntu 14.04. I'm receiving this error code

```
 install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/vinitas/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-36-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/vinitas
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/vinitas/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vinitas/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

Are you installing it globally? You can use

```
npm install -g electron
```

Comment: i used this command but i am having this error        npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/electron-prebuilt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/electron-prebuilt

Comment: Ah, well you may want to try reinstalling NPM?

Comment: i tried . I'm receiving this error code                                                                                     npm ERR! cwd /home/electron
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/electron
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/electron'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/electron/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0